# Diferencia entre "compile" y "implementation" en archivo gradle

Tags: android, firebase

He añadido **firebase** a mi proyecto mediante el asistente que proporciona AS, pero al momento de añadir la dependencia, me aparece de forma diferente.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

Pero otro servicio de google complila de la siguiente manera :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

Como pueden ver solo cambia la palabra al principio, Ahora quisiera saber la diferencia entre **implementation** y **complle** o simplemente es un sinónimo.

Al momento de actualizar el archivo `.gradle` no me genera error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A partir de la versión 3.0 de Gradle, `compile` es obsoleto y debes usar `api` o `implementation`.

`api` se usa para incluir dependencias que serán exportadas por el API de tu librería e `implementation` se usa para incluir una dependencia que será usada internamente en tu proyecto.

En definitiva, en Android si usas Gradle 3.0 o superior debes usar `implementation` en vez de `compile`.

Gradle **no te va a dar error** si usas `compile`, pero eventualmente lo quitarán y deberás usar si o si `implementation`.

Puedes ver la documentación [aquí](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) (en inglés).

Comment: Gracias por la info :D

Answer (score 1):

La diferencias principales que existen ente **compile** e **implementation** son:

Que **implementation** tiene muchas ventajas y mejoras con respecto a **compile** las cuales son:

1. Compilación más rápida gracias al tamaño reducido de classpath.
2. Menos recompilaciones cuando cambian las dependencias.

**Nota:** La configuración compile aún existe, pero no debe utilizarse, ya que no ofrecerá las garantías que brindan las configuraciones api.